# Shoutcast Listeners Behind a Proxy

Tags: w3c, shoutcast, internet-radio

I would like some assistance with calculating the sessions for Shoutcast listeners behind a proxy (multiple listeners only using one IP Address).

I am using the W3C log to get listener info and can see that I can use the unique IPs, connected_time and start time to calculate if it is a valid session. This works but what to do if you get multiple connections all from the same IP address. To make this even more difficult, what if all these connections used the same agent?

I am using php to parse the log files but this should matter as I am just looking for the "formula" to use.

I also tried using Sawmill to parse the log files but it looks like Sawmill consolidates these connections into one session. I can however split these sessions if the agents were different.

Is there some kind of formula I can use or should I just accept that, unless these multiple connections use different agents, there is truly no way of splitting them up?

Comment: It's really no different, except that the IP address will be the same for all listeners.  There will still be a separate connection for each listener, and therefore a separate log entry.  Unfortunately, SHOUTcast isn't going to obey the `X-Forwarded-For` header.

Comment: Thanks for your replay Brad. But how do you calculate whether it is a separate connection? For now we will just treat the separate connections as one until I have found a solution. Too bad the UID in the stats pages don't get mentioned in the w3c logs. That would have sorted the problem out.

Comment: Each line is a separate connection...  reconfigure Sawmill.

Comment: Actually not Brad. You get a line for a new connection and then every time a track has finished playing or when there is a disconnection. When a new connection happens, the sc-bytes, connected time and average transfers are 0. Then only once a track changed or the disconnection happens these values will update. Since all these connections will have the same IP, there is no way of separating them into different connections, unless you use the stats pages in real time. Also, we decided to not use Sawmill as it will be way too expensive for what we need it for.

Comment: Ah, my apologies, it's been a long time since I've dealt with that W3C log on SHOUTcast.  Is there a reason you have to use the W3C log?  Why not use the regular log you get out of the admin panel?  I run a service which streams from this log to Google Analytics, and it uses those UIDs to differentiate between streams.  https://audiopump.co/analytics-connector.html  However, this only works for legacy versions of SHOUTcast, as the new versions have a bug where a log tail connection cannot be maintained for more than few seconds.  (The bug has been there for years, but they wont' fix it.  :-( )

Comment: Just using the admin stats page has a huge risk of missing data as you will have to read these pages every second for 500 stream IDs. My custom php script takes about 4 seconds to read through everything, which is still too slow. The w3c log way seems to be the only other solution unless you want to spend $1000s a month on licensing fees for Sawmill. Also, the main reason for this is better listener stats for our clients. At the moment we are using logstash to parse the w3c logs into a DB and then we use php to do our calculations.

Comment: There's a mode on legacy SHOUTcast servers for streaming the log... no reason to poll the page.  Basically, you open the stream, the server sends you the last 1,000 lines of the log, plus anything new in streaming mode as it comes in, in real time.  I used to have PHP code to do this... if I still had it handy, I'd send it to you.  These days I'm using Node.js.